# Seperating options from non-option arguments in a command-line program

Tags: c, command-line

I am trying to write a limited version of ls w/ some options.

However, I am stuck on the problem of parsing out my options from my arguments in a clean manner.

For example:

`$ ls -l -t somefile anotherFile`

`$ ls somefile -lt anotherFile`

have the same behavior.

This poses two problems for me:

1. It makes using argc a bit more difficult. For example I would consider the arguments `ls -lt` and `ls` to both have 0 arguments (other than the name of the command) however argc counts `-l` as an argument.

Therefore the naive implementation of :

```
if( argc == 1) {list all the contents of cwd}
```

does not work.

Is there a built-in way to get the options as well as the option count, or do I have to roll my own function?

2. I have to consider all the different ways options can be arranged and be careful not to get an option mixed up as a file name or directory name. It seems like the cleanest solution is to separate the options from the file arguments from the start. Is there an idiomatic way to do this / is there standard library calls that do this?

Comment: One common way of doing this (grep and tar come to mind) is to use the argument `--` to indicate that the following arguments are input and not to be processed as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in argument parsing help, but [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) is the "standard" method for argument parsing.

For simple apps, I sometimes roll my own with something like:

```
int pos=0;
argc--;argv++;
while (argc > 0) {
  if (*argv[0]=='-') {
     switch ((*argv)[1]) {
       case 'l': //-l argument
         save_option_l(++argv);
         argc--; //we consumed one name
         break;
       //... other -options here ...
       default:
         usage("unrecognized option %s", *argv);   
     }
   }
   else {
     save_positional_argument(argv,pos++);
   }
   argv++;
   argc--;
}
```

In this case, I require the modifiers to directly follow the flags. Don't support variable usage like your first example, unless there are very strong reasons to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Gnu's implementation of [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html), it will do all that for you.

Posix standard `getopt` terminates option processing when it hits the first non-option argument. That conforms to Posix guidelines for utility argument parsing, and many of us prefer this behaviour. But others like the ability to intermingle options and non-options, and that's the norm for Gnu utilities unless you set an environment variable with the ungainly name `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

Consistent with that preference, Gnu `getopt` parses arguments:

> The default is to permute the contents of argv while scanning it so that eventually all the non-options are at the end. This allows options to be given in any order, even with programs that were not written to expect this.

Note the wording about permuting arguments. This means that if you start with

```
ls somefile -lt anotherFile
```

Gnu `getopt` will:

1. Report a `l`
2. Report a `t`
3. Report end of options (-1), leaving `optind` with the value 2 and `argv` now looking like:

   ```
   ls -lt somefile anotherFile
   ```

So now you can process your non-option arguments with:

```
for (int argno = optind; argno < argc; ++argno) {
  /* Do something with argv[argno] */
}
```

Also, you can tell how many non-option arguments you received with `argc-optind`, and if `argc == optind`, you know there weren't any.

Unbundling `-lt` into two options is standard Posix `getopt behaviour`. You can combine options lime that as long as the first one doesn't take an argument.